# Find the time where their velocity is equivalent

Tags: vectors

The question is:

> The equations of movement of 2 particles are:
> $$x_1=3t^2+5t+6 \quad m$$ $$x_2=6t+8 \quad m$$
> Find the exact time where both will have the same velocity.

So i've tried this: $$\vec{v}=\frac{dx}{dt}$$ basically differentiated both to get $$\vec{v_1}=6t+5\quad m/s$$ $$\vec{v_2}=6\quad m/s$$ and then i got their magnitude $|\vec{v_1}|$ and $|\vec{v_2}|$ as this $$|\vec{v_1}=\sqrt{36t^2+5^2}$$ $$|\vec{v_2}|=6$$ and then equated both to get the instant time where both velocities are equivalent, $$36t^2+5^2=6^2$$ $$t^2=\frac{11}{36}=\sqrt{\frac{11}{36}}$$ is this correct? i'm afraid i should have equated both velocity **vectors** and not their magnitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocities are in the $x$ direction, so the magnitudes would just be the absolute values of $6t+5$ and $6$.  There is no need to take them.  Just equate the two velocities, giving $6t+5=6$ and solve for $t$.

Comment: so, if it were to be not in the x direction, would we have to take the abs value?

Comment: As long as they are in the same direction you do not need to take the absolute value.  If they are not in the same direction the velocities do not match at all.  The only reason to take the absolute value is if the components $6t$ and $5$ were in different directions, but they are not.

Comment: You don't take absolute value when the question asks about 'equivalent velocity' regardless of x-direction or otherwise.  Velocity is a vector. You only take absolute values for magnitudes, or speeds.

Answer (score 1):

This is one-dimensional motion. You're solving the problem as if it's two-dimensional motion. No vector addition needed!

Solve $6t+5=6$ and you're done!

Comment: so, if it were to be not ONLY on the x direction, we would have to take their magnitude?

Comment: The magnitude of the velocity (generally a vector) is the speed (a scalar). In this case, though, you'd have more than just one equation for each particle. You'd have the $x$ equation and the $y$ equation for each one, and would solve each component individually. Then, when you have each one, you can use the magnitude piece to get the speeds.

Comment: yeah and then solve for t by equating both speeds right?

Comment: There is no need to take the magnitude if you're trying to equate two velocities. Velocities are vectors. You want the vectors to be the same. There isn't a reason to take magnitudes unless you want the velocity in polar form or something.

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered by others. The answer is the solution of the equation $6t+5 = 6$ which means $t=\frac{1}{6}$

I just wanted to clarify some things for Xetrez that I think he might be misunderstanding.

1. 'Velocity' is a vector by definition. The corresponding scalar (magnitude) is 'speed'.

Note that the problem doesn't give any vector notation or any direction information, so we can assume all velocities are along a single axis. You can presume there's a unit vector $\hat i$ that is left off for convenience.

So if we're dealing with a single axis, does that mean direction doesn't matter? No! You can still have forward (positive) or backwards (negative) along a single axis. So if a problem asks about velocity, that means the sign matters. So you wouldn't take absolute values when the question is about velocities. If it asks about 'speed' then only magnitude matters, hence the sign wouldn't matter in that case, and you'd take absolute values.

2. You didn't take the absolute value correctly. This was an unnecessary step, but I just wanted to point out the error anyway.

$|\vec{v_1}| = \sqrt{(6t+5)^2} = \sqrt{36t^2+60t+25}$.

If the problem restricted t to $t \ge 0$, then $|\vec{v_1}| = |6t+5| = 6t+5$

Since the whole thing is along a single component $\vec{v_1} = (6t+5)\hat i$. You just take the absolute value of that one component, just like taking the absolute value of any number.

I wanted to point this out because I thought maybe you got confused between taking the magnitude of a vector with two perpendicular components.

If you had this:

$\vec{v_1} = (6t)\hat i + 5\hat j$

Then the magnitude of the vector would be: $\sqrt{(6t)^2+5^2}$. This is because $\hat i$ and $\hat j$ are perpendicular unit vectors, one along the x-axis and one along the y-axis.

If you weren't confusing these two ideas, then I apologize.

One final thing... if the problem were asking about all times when the speeds were the same, then what we'd want is

$|\vec{v_1}| = |\vec{v_2}| \iff $

$|6t+5| = |6| \iff$

$|6t+5| = 6 \iff$

$6t+5 = 6$ OR $6t+5 = -6$

or you could solve $\sqrt{36t^2+60t+25} = 6$ and get the same solutions.

So if the problem were asking about times when speeds were the same we'd get $t=\frac{1}{6}$ or $t=\frac{-11}{6}$. If the problem had the additional restriction that $t \ge 0$ we'd have only $t=\frac{1}{6}$ for the speed case also.

Comment: thanks for the clarification too